# Switch small program does not let me see result

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am learning the `switch` statement of C. This is my small program and it runs and does the calculation but doesn't let me see the result of the operation. The black window shows up so that I input the numbers and the operator and then for a fraction of a second shows the result and disappears. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int num1, num2, ans=0;
char ch, name;

printf("Enter a value: ");
scanf("%d", &num1);

printf("Enter a second value: ");
scanf("%d", &num2);

printf("Input * To multiply\
              + To add\
              - To subtract: ");
scanf(" %c", &ch);

switch(ch)
{
case'*':
    ans=num1 * num2;
    printf("%d times %i equals: %i",num1,num2,ans);
    break;

case'+':
    ans=num1+num2;
    printf("%i plus %i equals: %d",num1,num2,ans);
    break;

case'-':
    ans=num1-num2;
    printf("%d minus %d equals: %d",num1,num2,ans);
    break;

default:
    printf("Range numbers");
}

getchar();
return ch;
}
```

Comment: Got two good answers already -- however as a side comment, you should stick to one style using %d or %i, but don't use both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch small prgram does not let me input option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858615/switch-small-prgram-does-not-let-me-input-option)

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to output buffering. Add newlines (\n) last in your formatting strings.

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie, you should end all your `printf` format string with an escaped newline `\n`, i.e. `printf("%i plus %i equals %d\n", num1, num2, ans);` (or you should call `fflush(stdout);` just after the end of the switch before the `getch` and before all your `scanf`).

Comment: Add a call to `fflush` before every input, i.e. `scanf` or `getch`. And learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux) and to ask your compiler for warnings & debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` on Linux)